# Access each property in array - ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to access each object of my array and  verify if the property PRIMARY is false or true.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="emailAtivo in emailList.emails">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{emailAtivo.email}}">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" tooltip="E-mail" tooltip-append-to-body="true">&nbsp;<i class="fa" ng-class="PutPrimary()"></i>&nbsp;</a>
                <a href="#" oak-confirm="ExcluirEmailClick(emailAtivo.id)" message="@Resources.Common.AreYouSure" yes="@Resources.Common.Yes" no="@Resources.Common.Cancel" class="btn btn-danger">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I made this function:

```
$scope.PutPrimary = function () {
        if ($scope.emailList.emails.primary === false) {
            return "fa-star-o";
        } else {
            return "fa-star";
        }
    }
```

And my Array is:

```
{
"emails": [
    {
        "id": 25,
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "primary": true,
        "notify": true,
        "deleted": false
    },
    {
        "id": 26,
        "email": "teste@teste2.com",
        "primary": false,
        "notify": true,
        "deleted": false
    },
    {
        "id": 48,
        "email": "teste@teste.com",
        "primary": false,
        "notify": true,
        "deleted": false
    },
    {
        "id": 49,
        "email": "teste@teste3.com",
        "primary": false,
        "notify": true,
        "deleted": false
    }
]
```

}

My class always is "fa-star" in all e-mail of this collection.

Comment: what is the code that declares $scope.emailList ? Are you using ng-repeat anywhere, if not then how is this related to angular?

Comment: Yes @Mike I use ng-repeat and exchange the HTML code.

Comment: instead `PutPrimary` you can just use `ng-class="{"fa-star-o": !emailAtivo.primary, "fa-star":emailAtivo.primary}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass emailAtivo into the PutPrimary function, at the moment you are trying to look at the 'primary' property on the whole array